# How to Refer to a Column by ID or Index Number

Tags: sql, oracle

In Oracle PL/SQL, I have run a query and am trying to read through each column for each row one by one so I can concatenate them together with a delimiter (hard format requirement). The script is used on multiple tables of varying sizes, so the number of columns is not known in advance. I used

```
SELECT COUNT(column_name) INTO NumColumns FROM all_tabs_cols
WHERE table_name = Table_Array(i);
```

where Table_Array has already been defined. This is in the middle of a for loop and has successfully gotten me a total number of columns. Table_Cursor is a SELECT * statement. After this I am trying to do something like

```
FOR j IN 0..NumColumns-1 LOOP
    FETCH TABLE_CURSOR.column(j) INTO DataValue;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT(DataValue || '/');
END LOOP
```

The above is pseudo code. It illustrates the concept I am after. I do not know PL/SQL well enough to know how to get a value like this out of a row. I am also worried about accidentally advancing the cursor while doing this. How can I accomplish this task?

Comment: Who not just use LISTAGG or some other aggregation function?

Comment: This is not how you should work with SQL -- SQL is set based -- as soon as you have a look you are in trouble.

Comment: @Hogan, I was afraid of that. What is a better way to get that information out then?

Comment: @OldProgrammer, LISTAGG would be great as I already used it to get the header information. The problem is it seems to only go down the column, not across the row. I have 1000 rows with 3 columns, I need 1/A1/B1/C1, then 2/A2/B2/C2, etc. down the list. Is there a way to make LISTAGG work across a single row?

Comment: @SandPiper - best way is to write some code that generates code that is fast and run that.   See my answer -- it is only one line long.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use some form of dynamic SQL.  Here is a quick example:

It builds the SQL statement that will select the '/' separated columns from the table you want.  Then it uses dynamic SQL to run that SQL statement.

```
DECLARE
  p_table_name VARCHAR2(30) := 'DBA_OBJECTS';
  l_sql VARCHAR2(32000);

  TYPE varchar2tab IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(32000);
  l_array varchar2tab;

BEGIN
  SELECT 'SELECT ' || listagg(column_name,' ||''/''||') within group ( order by column_id ) || ' FROM ' || owner || '.' || table_name || ' WHERE ROWNUM <= 100'
  INTO l_sql
  FROM dba_tab_columns
  where table_Name = 'DBA_OBJECTS'
  group by owner, table_Name;

  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE l_sql BULK COLLECT INTO l_array;

  FOR i in l_array.first .. l_array.last LOOP
    dbms_output.put_line(l_array(i));
  END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: This worked like a champ. The only thing I changed was I put together the entire l_sql as a single string before running EXECUTE IMMEDIATE. Thank you very much!

Comment: You're welcome.  Make sure you add appropriate error handling.  Oracle rows can be (much!) longer than 32,000 bytes.  Also, this won't work for tables with certain data types (e.g., `LONG`).

Comment: I am still learning SQL. For my curiosity, why will it not work with the LONG data type? And what others?

Comment: `LONG` cannot be implicitly converted to a VARCHAR2.  In fact, it notoriously cannot even be _explicitly_ converted to a VARCHAR2.  They're just a pain to work with and I'm 99% sure that everyone would be thrilled if Oracle just got rid of them.  Other types?  I'm not sure... anything that cannot be implicitly converted to a VARCHAR2.  `LONG` always jumps to mind.  Maybe some of the specialized Oracle Spatial data types might be problems.  All the common data types: `NUMBER`, `DATE`, `VARCHAR2` will be fine.  However (see next comment...)

Comment: `DATE` columns will be implicitly converted using your `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` setting.  It'd be better practice to build your SQL using a `TO_DATE(_columnName_,'DD-MON-YYYY')` or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

This is how your code should look:

```
SELECT F1 || ', ' || F2 || ', ' || ... || ', ' || FN
FROM TABLE
```

**NO LOOPS**

---

Here is how you can generate code that does not use loops.
Note, if you want you can take out the where statement and generate the code for the whole database.
Test with just one table first.

```
SELECT 'SELECT '|| LISTAGG(COLUMN_NAME, ' || '', '' || ') || ' FROM '||TABLE_NAME as sql_stm
FROM ALL_TAB_COLUMNS 
WHERE TABLE_NAME='tablename'
GROUP BY TABLE_NAME;
```

Comment: So you mean to say, if he has 1000 tables he has to do it the above way for each time. I hope you understood my point.

Comment: This is not helpful. My problem is exactly like @Raj_Te said. I have a lot of tables, and the table structures change occasionally. I do not have control over that. I have to use dynamic SQL scripting to get it. I don't know what the table column names are, that is why I need to refer to it by index.

Comment: **EXACTLY**  Write some sql that generates the above code.  Don't use loops.  loops are slow.

Comment: Minor: it's `LISTAGG()`, not `LIST_AGG()`.