# Writing query with dynamic amount of output columns in Oracle (10g) SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I read about PIVOT but it is not available in Oracle 10g. What I actually need is, for example, to output some result with the amount of columns user inputed. Any ideas how to do this would be appreciated.

Edit.
What I am trying to do is equivalent to this: user inputs some date and number of days following after this date, First line of output shows the day of the week, the second line shows what month it is.                                            For instance, input :start_date =  "30/08/2016", :number = 3. Output is:                            
  1      2     3     
                                                                                                    tue   wed   thu    
                                                                                                    aug   aug  sep                                                                                                    
  I hope this gave some understanding.

Comment: show your related schema , data sample and expected result  ..

Comment: You'd need to write the query dynamically - see [this 12 year old blog post of mine](http://tonyandrews.blogspot.co.uk/search/label/pivot) for one way.

Comment: @TonyAndrews unfortunately there is used PIVOT, which is not possible in my 10g version.

Comment: @БейбутТукибаев No, there is a **package** called `pivot` that I wrote and the code for it is there in the blog.  12 years ago Oracle did not have PIVOT!

Comment: @scaisEdge I do not have any pieces of code, but the actual task is the following: user inputs some number which is amounts of days, and gets result so that information about each day is displayed separately in each column.

Comment: You must have a table you are trying to select from - can you share that with us?

Comment: @TonyAndrews edited the post, hope it helps

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121116/discussion-between---and-tony-andrews).

Answer (score 1):

I believe I had a similar issue I was trying to solve, and the solution I found can be seen here: [Concatenating All Columns of Each Record Into One Entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38857363/concatenating-all-columns-of-each-record-into-one-entry)

However, your question is very vague. I was pretty new to SQL too, and I understand you might not have any idea where to even start with the code. But, if you at least post some pseudo code, or even better an idea of what your output should look like, you will get a lot more help. Post some of that and it will be easier to get a closer code solution for you.

Comment: I am sorry, but I do not have any code now, I just want to get an idea how to make it possible to output exactly same amount of columns as user inputed. This is the main point I am trying to solve.

Comment: Understand no code. You need to be a little more specific on what you are trying to get out though. Column names, how you want the input to be, etc.